# Put widget inside RowExpander in GXT

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

Is there a way to display widget in the expanded area? RowExpander uses AbstractCell which can display only simple html. It is possible to take html from widget and place it into cell but the buttons in the widget won't work after this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend the RowExpander class and/or override the method beforeExpand. Here's what I did and it works great for inserting a button or in my case i needed a grid:

```
public class RowWidgetExpander extends RowExpander {

private Widget widget;

public void setWidget(Widget widget) {
    this.widget = widget;
}

public Widget getWidget() {
    return widget;
}

@Override
protected boolean beforeExpand(ModelData model, Element body, El row, int rowIndex) {
    RowExpanderEvent e = new RowExpanderEvent(this);
    e.setModel(model);
    e.setRowIndex(rowIndex);
    e.setBodyElement(body);

    if(fireEvent(Events.BeforeExpand, e)) {
        body.setInnerText("");
        body.appendChild(widget.getElement());
        ComponentHelper.doAttach(widget);

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inserting the widget to the grid. You can put widget on the grid.

Insert grid in AbsolutPanel. And after expand event you can insert widget into the AbslolutPanel and set position on expanded area.

Set the height of the AbsolutPanel such as total height of grid (all grid lines). And AbsolutPanel put inside a Scroll Panel.

With this solution, You have a widget - not only pure html. And you do not have to worry about Scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Try this workaround to get events working again in the row expander.
 http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?250316-RowExpander-dosn-t-fire-events-on-ContentCell

Comment: Please quote the relevant portions of your link that answer the question.  The reason being that SO is intended to answer questions far beyond the moment, but also in the future when people google for answers to their problem.  If at some point in the future this link breaks, then your answer will then be useless to others